# connection from menu doesnt work

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i have a menu class that contains all the class in the project, when i click on the links to the other class i get error in the opera browser.
"This webpage is not available

Opera's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured."
 i cant find the problem in the code.
thank you very much!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class meni : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="meni.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.meni" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
  <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" BackColor="#B5C7DE" 
        DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Larger" 
        ForeColor="#284E98" StaticSubMenuIndent="12px">
      <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
      <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
      <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" />
      <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
      <Items>
          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://localhost:56717/Customer.aspx" 
              Text="costumers" Value="costumers"></asp:MenuItem>
          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://localhost:56717/Vendor.aspx" Text="Vendors" 
              Value="Vendors"></asp:MenuItem>
          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://localhost:56717/region.aspx" Text="Regions" 
              Value="Regions"></asp:MenuItem>
          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://localhost:56717/Service.aspx" Text="Service" 
              Value="Service"></asp:MenuItem>
          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://localhost:56717/usage.aspx" Text="Usages" 
              Value="Usages"></asp:MenuItem>
          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://localhost:56717/comDisp.aspx" 
              Text="Commitments" Value="Commitments"></asp:MenuItem>
      </Items>
      <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
      <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
      <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />

    </asp:Menu>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue with your hrefs on the menu items - instead of NavigateURL="http://localhost:56717/Vendor.aspx" try using relative URLs such as:

```
NavigateURL="~/Vendor.aspx"
```